# OS X Lion - cannot run spotlight, mail, iCal etc

Tags: macos, osx-lion, filesystems

Whenever I try to run Mail or iCal I get the following error:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/KerberosHelper.framework/Versions/A/KerberosHelper
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/CalendarStore.framework/Versions/A/CalendarStore
  Reason: image not found
```

So it seems that the issue is missing KerberosHelper whatever it is.

The problem might be connected to the fact, that the system could not be loaded [ before the login screen I could see progress bar and CPU automatically was shut downed. ]. I entered single user mode with `cmd + s` and fixed the `invalid node structure` error with command `fsck_hfs -ypr /dev/disk02` [ or something like this ]. After rebooting CPU I could not open mail.. any ideas how to fix this? In addition, I cannot find any application in spotlight - it looks up for a long time and then pop ups no results. When I tried `sudo mdutil -E /` command, I got error 'spotlight service is disabled'. Help please :/

Comment: Wouldn't now be a good time to upgrade to Mountain Lion? You can also reinstall Lion from the [recovery partition](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718). It's like an upgrade install so it shouldn't overwrite or remove user files.

Comment: @Lauri Ranta thanks for the suggestion, I might want to try your solution during weekend. Still hope it can be done in an easier way